# Unmelt a pandas dataframe to remove NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

Given the following data:

```py
s = '{"PassengerId":{"0":1,"1":2,"2":3},"Survived":{"0":0,"1":1,"2":1},"Pclass":{"0":3,"1":1,"2":3}}'
df = pd.read_json(s)
```

Which looks as:

```
   PassengerId  Survived  Pclass
0            1         0       3
1            2         1       1
2            3         1       3
```

Assume that it has been melted to

```py
m = df.melt()
print(m)

      variable  value
0  PassengerId      1
1  PassengerId      2
2  PassengerId      3
3     Survived      0
4     Survived      1
5     Survived      1
6       Pclass      3
7       Pclass      1
8       Pclass      3
```

I would like to know how to revert the melted `m` to the original `df`.

I have tried something similar to the following:

```py
m=df.melt().pivot(columns='variable', values='value').reset_index(drop=True)
m.columns.name = None
```

which gives

```py
   PassengerId  Pclass  Survived
0          1.0     NaN       NaN
1          2.0     NaN       NaN
2          3.0     NaN       NaN
3          NaN     NaN       0.0
4          NaN     NaN       1.0
5          NaN     NaN       1.0
6          NaN     3.0       NaN
7          NaN     1.0       NaN
8          NaN     3.0       NaN
​
```

as can be seen, each row contains information about a single column only, there are lots of `NaN` values in there that I would like to lose.

Comment: check Q10 in the link

Comment: @YOBEN_S this is *not* a duplicate - there is not an ID column in the example I have given

Comment: Check the question 10 in the link .

Comment: *How do I convert a DataFrame from long to wide by pivoting on ONLY two columns? Given,*

Comment: @YOBEN_S the answer has additional information that's relevant - are you going to update the thread you've linked with that information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for new column used for `index` parameter in [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
m['new'] = m.groupby('variable').cumcount()

df = m.pivot(columns='variable', values='value', index='new')
print (df)

variable  PassengerId  Pclass  Survived
new                                    
0                   1       3         0
1                   2       1         1
2                   3       3         1
```

Or:

```
df = (m.assign(new = m.groupby('variable').cumcount())
       .pivot(columns='variable', values='value', index='new'))
print (df)

variable  PassengerId  Pclass  Survived
new                                    
0                   1       3         0
1                   2       1         1
2                   3       3         1
```